# how to find network active time?

Tags: ifconfig, uptime

How to know uptime ,downtime with timestamps of all connections of `ifconfig`. For my case they are three eth0,wlan0 and ppp0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261759/get-notified-about-network-interface-change-on-linux

Answer (score 1):

*Some* of the information you are requesting can be gleaned from /var/log/syslog, e.g:

```
grep wlan /var/log/syslog
```

But the usefulness of that information also depends on how you are network connecting; dhcp  or static network connections, etc.